# Inconsistent datatypes : CAST REF?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've this schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tree_t
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE element_t AS OBJECT (
  libelle varchar2(100),
  parent REF tree_t,
) NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tree_t UNDER element_t()
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE leaf_t UNDER element_t()
/
```

And I'm trying to insert in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE elements OF element_t;
```

For an element_t without parent, no problem :

```
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (tree_t('first', NULL));
```

But with a parent :

```
INSERT INTO elements 
VALUES (tree_t('second', 
    (SELECT REF(e) 
     FROM elements e 
     WHERE e.libelle = 'first')));
```

I've this result:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF CINETREE.TREE_T 
got REF CINETREE.ELEMENT_T
```

Can I keep this schema, and how to make insertions?
(with CAST?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TREAT should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO elements 
VALUES (tree_t('second', 
    (SELECT TREAT(REF(e) AS REF tree_t)
     FROM elements e 
     WHERE e.libelle = 'first')));
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as the accepted answer. It's an essential feedback to the community so people having a similar issue immediately see what answer best solved the problem.